# How to switchmap - emitting an object containing both original and new observable?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I want to create an observable which first gets a value from an async function, then use that value to get another value asynchronously, and emit an object containing both values.

Something like:

```
function getValue1(){
    // asynchronously...
    return Observable.of(value1);
}

function getValue2UsingValue1(value1){
    // asynchronously...
    // value1 is needed to get value2...
    return Observable.of(value2);
}

getValue1()
    .switchMap(value1=> getValue2UsingValue1(value1))
    //...
    // I want to get an observable that emits an object containing value1 
    // and value2: {value1: value1, value2: value2}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is really confusing. What's `getValue2UsingValue1()`? What means "*I don't want to subscribe to the original observable in order to get value2*"? Can you make a demo on plnkr or jsfiddle?

Comment: I edited the question, I hope it's clearer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can make:

```
var value1Cached = getValue1().publishReplay(1);
value1Cached.connect();
var value2 = value1Cached.concatMap(value1 => getValue2UsingValue1(value1));

Observable.forkJoin(value1Cached, value2)
    .map(values => {
        return {'value1': values[0], 'value2': values[1]};
    })
    .subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

I'm using `publishReplay()` operator to turn this Observable into a `ConnectableObservable` with `ReplaySubject` inside to support caching. I guess you don't want to call the `getValue1()` twice.

Then `forkJoin()` waits for both Observables to complete and emits their values in an array.

See live demo: https://jsbin.com/posanup/3/edit?js,console

This prints to console:

```
[object Object] {
  value1: "value1",
  value2: "value2"
}
```